# PHP - ldap_search() filter. How to search for user

Tags: php, active-directory, filter, ldap

$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] returns the username of the user logged in to an Active Directory. I want to retrive this users info by using ldap_search().

This is what I have now:

```
$ad = // ldap_connection id
$filter = "(|(sn=$username*)(givenname=$username*))";
$attr = array("displayname", "mail", "mobile", "homephone", "telephonenumber", "streetaddress", "postalcode", "physicaldeliveryofficename", "l");
$dn = // OU, DC etc..

ldap_search($ad,$dn,$filter,$attr);
```

It works, but i'm not sure it will work if two users have almost the same names.
How do I only search for their unique username so that i always only get one user?

Comment: $filter = "(samaccountname=$username)"; <- is this correct? "samaccountname" is the unique username right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sAMAccountName` is the username-attribute used in Active Directory, so `(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))` would be the correct filter to check the LDAP for a given username (with `%s` being replaced by the actual username naturally).

Please be aware that you need to handle special characters in `$username` to avoid malformed filters or at worst malicious LDAP injections (see **RFC 2254**):

> Any control characters with an ACII
>   code < 32 as well as the characters
>   with special meaning in LDAP filters
>   "*", "(", ")", and "\" (the backslash)
>   are converted into the representation
>   of a backslash followed by two hex
>   digits representing the hexadecimal
>   value of the character.

Answer (score 3):

`ldap_search()` will find all matching entries, you will have to verify the result.
Let's say `$link` is your link to the LDAP database created with `ldap_connect()`ldap_get_entries($link, $result)
You can verify that like this :

```
$result = ldap_search();
if(ldap_count_entries($link, $result) === 1) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
$result = ldap_search();
$entries = ldap_get_entries($link, $result);
if(sizeof($entries) === 1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ldap_search supports both and & and or |.  If you want to search multiple attributes for the occurrence of your search string you can do it as follows. This will search for a person where your search string ($str) in in samaccountname or name or title.

```
$filter="(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|(sAMAccountName=*{$str}*)(name=*{$str}*)(title=*{$str}*)))";

$result=ldap_search($connection, $dn, $filter);
```